# NetSuite 64bit ODBC Driver installation on Ubuntu 18.04 Cluster giving error:- Can't open lib '/opt/netsuite/odbcclient/lib64/ivoa27.so

Tags: ubuntu, drivers, 64bit, odbc

Have been running around this issue since 2-3 days now with no luck. Hope someone guides me and help resolve this issue here.

I am running a Python application from /home/admin/app/example.py directory in a 3 node Ubuntu 18.04 clustered environment which is supposed to connect to NetSuite via ODBC and read list of tables. The code and directory setup is same across all 3 nodes. There's a load balancer routing request to all these 3 nodes.

Here's example how the connection is made via PyODBC module:

```
import pyodbc
cnxn = pyodbc.connect('DSN=NetSuite;UID=user;PWD=pass'.format(dsn, uid, pwd), autocommit=True)
        cursor=cnxn.cursor()
        tables_list = []
        for row in cursor.tables():
            tables_list.append(row.table_name)
print (tables_list)
```

However, while running the python application on cluster, I am always getting error as:- **Can't open lib '/opt/netsuite/odbcclient/lib64/ivoa27.so**; even though the driver file, all its dependencies (via ldd command) and all the path variables i.e. $LD_LIBRARY_PATH, $ODBCINI and $OASDK_ODBC_HOME exists and is set to be available system-wide (added under /etc/environment file) as below on all the 3 nodes:

> PYTHON_APP_HOME=/home/admin/app/
> LD_LIBRARY_PATH="/opt/netsuite/odbcclient/lib64"
> ODBCINI="/opt/netsuite/odbcclient/odbc64.ini"
> OASDK_ODBC_HOME="/opt/netsuite/odbcclient/lib64"

Here's the output from "ldd" command for driver dependencies:

```
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  3277375 Jul 25 16:03 ivoa27.so

/opt/netsuite/odbcclient/lib64$ ldd /opt/netsuite/odbcclient/lib64/ivoa27.so
        linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007fff401a2000)
        librt.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librt.so.1 (0x00007fee1d589000)
        libdl.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0x00007fee1d385000)
        libicuuc.so.42 => /opt/netsuite/odbcclient/lib64/libicuuc.so.42 (0x00007fee1d12b000)
        libicudata.so.42 => /opt/netsuite/odbcclient/lib64/libicudata.so.42 (0x00007fee1c0e6000)
        libpam.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpam.so.0 (0x00007fee1bed8000)
        libpthread.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007fee1bcb9000)
        libstdc++.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 (0x00007fee1b930000)
        libm.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x00007fee1b592000)
        libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007fee1b37a000)
        libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007fee1af89000)
        /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007fee1db3c000)
        libaudit.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libaudit.so.1 (0x00007fee1ad60000)
        libcap-ng.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcap-ng.so.0 (0x00007fee1ab5b000)
```

Below is how the steps were performed as per Netsuite driver README.txt instructions and the ODBC driver is setup similarly across all the 3 nodes on Ubuntu 18.04 OS.

1. The Netsuite 64bit Linux driver files/folders are unpacked and copied at location:
   **$cd /opt/netsuite/odbcclient/***. This entire dir,sub-dir & files within have both r+x permissions.
2. Installed libraries **$sudo apt install unixodbc && apt-get install unixodbc-dev**
3. Executed script/command provided by Netsuite from dir /opt/netsuite/odbcclient:- **$source oaodbc64.sh** (since it's a bash shell). This sets up the same variables as shown above.
4. From the same directory/folder ran below command for registering it as system-wide Driver:

> $**sudo odbcinst -i -d -f /opt/netsuite/odbcclient/odbcinst.ini**

which returned message as:

> odbcinst: Driver installed. Usage count increased to 1.
> Target directory is /etc
> odbcinst: Driver installed. Usage count increased to 1.
> Target directory is /etc

5. Then ran below command also for installing it as system DSN:-

> $**sudo odbcinst -i -s -l -f /opt/netsuite/odbcclient/odbc64.ini**

After this, checked /etc directory where both odbc.ini and odbcinst.ini files where created/registered. Both *.ini files were also given execute permissions to all.

```
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 500 Jul 24 10:31 odbc.ini
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 199 Jul 24 10:31 odbcinst.ini

$odbcinst -j
unixODBC 2.3.4
DRIVERS............: /etc/odbcinst.ini
SYSTEM DATA SOURCES: /etc/odbc.ini
FILE DATA SOURCES..: /etc/ODBCDataSources
USER DATA SOURCES..: /opt/netsuite/odbcclient/odbc64.ini
SQLULEN Size.......: 8
SQLLEN Size........: 8
SQLSETPOSIROW Size.: 8

$odbcinst -q -d
[ODBC Drivers]
[NetSuite ODBC Drivers 8.1]

$odbcinst -q -s
[NetSuite]
[ODBC]
```

I am also able to connect from each individual nodes via isql and also by running the example.py via python shell locally.

> $**isql -v 'NetSuite' 'user' 'pass'**

```
+---------------------------------------+
| Connected!                            |
|                                       |
| sql-statement                         |
| help [tablename]                      |
| quit                                  |
|                                       |
+---------------------------------------+
SQL>
```

But when running the same on cluster, it gives same error always. Please help. I am sure am missing something.

Here's the output of odbc.ini and odbcinst.ini files from /etc directory:

```
/etc$ more odbcinst.ini
[ODBC Drivers]
NetSuite ODBC Drivers 8.1=Installed
UsageCount=1

[NetSuite ODBC Drivers 8.1]
APILevel=1
ConnectFunctions=YYN
Driver=ivoa27.so
DriverODBCVer=03.52
FileUsage=0
SQLLevel=1
UsageCount=1

/etc$ more odbc.ini
[ODBC Data Sources]
NetSuite=NetSuite ODBC Drivers 8.1

[NetSuite]
Driver=/opt/netsuite/odbcclient/lib64/ivoa27.so
Description=Connect to your NetSuite account
Host=XXXXX.connect.api.netsuite.com
Port=1708
ServerDataSource=NetSuite.com
Encrypted=1
Truststore=/opt/netsuite/odbcclient/cert/ca3.cer
CustomProperties=AccountID=XXXXX;RoleID=XXXX

[ODBC]
Trace=0
IANAAppCodePage=4
TraceFile=odbctrace.out
TraceDll=/opt/netsuite/odbcclient/lib64/ddtrc27.so
InstallDir=/opt/netsuite/odbcclient
```

Tried below other things that didn't work:

1. Added ODBC variable paths within .profile,.bashrc ,/etc/profile,/etc/bash.bashrc other than /etc/environment.
2. Changed the owner of /lib64/ folder and all files within it and *.ini files under /etc from root to admin.
3. By creating symbolic links:
   sudo ln -s /etc/odbcinst.ini /usr/local/etc/odbcinst.ini
   sudo ln -s /etc/odbc.ini /usr/local/etc/odbc.ini

Thanks !!

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATE - SOLVED !!** One important step that was missing from our end was the **reboot/restart of all the nodes** for those 3 variables to take into system-wide effect after it had been added into /etc/environment file(s).

In order to investigate, we printed below additional things into our code to ensure that it indeed is a 64 bit platform/architecture,  drivers and datasources are registered and listed. However, the variables were still showing blanks/none. That verified that although the variable path was set/effective locally when running from individual nodes. However, when running from outside/via remote session, the variable values didn't get apply.

```
import os
import pyodbc
import platform

print(platform.architecture())
print (pyodbc.drivers())
print(pyodbc.dataSources())
print(os.environ["LD_LIBRARY_PATH"])
print(os.environ["ODBCINI"])
print(os.environ["OASDK_ODBC_HOME"])
```

Before reboot:

```
[2020-07-27 18:46:51,948] {logging_mixin.py:112} INFO - ('64bit', 'ELF')
[2020-07-27 18:46:51,949] {logging_mixin.py:112} INFO - ['ODBC Drivers', 'NetSuite ODBC Drivers 8.1']
[2020-07-27 18:46:51,950] {logging_mixin.py:112} INFO - {'NetSuite': '/opt/netsuite/odbcclient/lib64/ivoa27.so', 'ODBC': ''}
[2020-07-27 18:46:51,950] {logging_mixin.py:112} INFO - Error: 'LD_LIBRARY_PATH'
```

After reboot:

```
[2020-07-28 06:11:59,961] {logging_mixin.py:112} INFO - ('64bit', 'ELF')
[2020-07-28 06:11:59,963] {logging_mixin.py:112} INFO - ['ODBC Drivers', 'NetSuite ODBC Drivers 8.1']
[2020-07-28 06:11:59,965] {logging_mixin.py:112} INFO - {'NetSuite': '/opt/netsuite/odbcclient/lib64/ivoa27.so', 'ODBC': ''}
[2020-07-28 06:11:59,965] {logging_mixin.py:112} INFO - /opt/netsuite/odbcclient/lib64
[2020-07-28 06:11:59,965] {logging_mixin.py:112} INFO - /opt/netsuite/odbcclient/odbc64.ini
[2020-07-28 06:11:59,965] {logging_mixin.py:112} INFO - /opt/netsuite/odbcclient/lib64
```